# inDesign indexing "fix"

Tags: adobe-indesign, error

When inserting new reference in Id I am getting this "fix" instead of page number. I have no idea how to fix.

[image: fix issue in indesign]

Comment: Well ... it isn't a roman number. Does "go to refererence" work for that entry?

Comment: I've never seen this before. If the reference is outside the spread it would be labeled "PB". If it's in overset text it would be labeled "PN". Could you post an image where we can see _where_ you have added the reference? Is it just in the main text flow?

Comment: yes @usr2564301 the link works- for that example, it took me to table of contents

Comment: @Wolff - nothing fancy, just highlighted the word in the second chapter of the book

Comment: I have had further unexpected and thrillingly strange behaviour after "fix". When indexing Cryptosporidium parvum I had many instances of the word "crypto" (more than 30) instead of a page number. I took the time to delete each by hand, now thinking I should have resolved it when I built the index.